# How to place the {label} of \TextField at top of field in a form with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, vertical-alignment, pdf, forms

When placing a high `\TextField[height=5cm]{label}` with `hyperref` the label (*TextFieldName* in the screenshot) is placed at the bottom.

How to move it to top (blue position) ?

I tried looking up alignment in the manual and elsewhere, but that doesn't seem to be a relevant keyword in this context.

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \TextField[ width=12cm, height=5cm, 
                multiline=true, name=tField]{TextFieldName}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general layout is defined through \LayoutTextField which you can redefine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\LayoutTextField#1#2{% label, field
  \def\Hy@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\Hy@temp\@empty
    #2%
  \else
    #1 \raisebox{\dimeval{-\height+\ht\strutbox}}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \TextField[ width=12cm, height=5cm,
                multiline=true, name=tField]{TextFieldName}
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution :) // I see \LayoutTextField is mentioned in the hyperref manual. Is there any documentation about how to use it? Or is it "self-evident" for the seasoned Latex-user?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found an obvious solution:

- the `\TextField{}` is treated like any other character
- i.e. it's aligned to the baseline
- so avoiding the label, placing it as normal text AND raising it solved this problem

[image: example]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
  \begin{Form}
    \rule{1cm}{1pt}
    % ~~~ \TextField{cLabel} ~~~~~
    \TextField[ width=1cm, height=2cm, 
                multiline=true, name=t1]{cLabel}
    \rule{1cm}{1pt} 
    % ~~~ text + \TextField{} ~~~~~     
    Lbl-text: \TextField[width=1cm, height=2cm, name=t2]{}
    \rule{1cm}{1pt}
    % ~~~ raised text + \TextField{} ~~~~~          
    \raisebox{2cm}{Raised text:} \TextField[width=1cm, height=2cm, name=t3]{}
    \rule{1cm}{1pt}
    
  \end{Form}
\end{document}
```