# Wrapping labels in a form

Tags: labels

I am trying to replicate this PDF form with TeX, with mixed success:

[image]

I am so far only good at rendering labels on one line like this:

[image]

My humble code uses \makebox for this, but apparently I cannot wrap labels with this approach:

```
            {\makebox[0.2\linewidth][l]{Position in Company: }}\uline{{<positionInCompany>}\hfill}{Nature of Business: }\uline{{<natureOfBusiness>}\hfill}\\
```

am I digging in the wrong direction?

Comment: Have a look at the question and its answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/654917/245790

Comment: Do you want to print it only? Then there are alternatives. If not: see my previous comment.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

I think using a table gives you the result you are looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{lp{4cm}lp{4cm}}
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Position in\\ Company:\end{tabular} &  & 
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Nature of\\ Business:\end{tabular} &  \\ \cline{2-2} 
\cline{4-4} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) Please make your code snippet compilable to simplify its use.

Comment: First time answering on stackexchange; I have edited the code block, is adding begin/end document and documentclass what you mean?

Comment: That and the potential packages needed to produce an output without errors. Typically, to be sure, create a new `.tex` file containing only your code snippet and try to compile it. If it returns a PDF without errors, that's what you want to post.

Comment: You can also check [this page on minimal working examples](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/184389) for more information

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the link for MWE!