# Should math papers be hand written before using LaTeX?

Tags: best-practices, thesis, author, journal-publishing, workflow

When I'm not writing a math paper, I write way faster by typing directly into a word processor. I form and revise sentences faster on the screen then I can on paper.

But typesetting math is slower than handwriting, and I think better with a pen. I already know it's best to handwrite symbol-heavy text before typing, but what about text that's symbol-light, like an abstract or introduction?

Should I write almost the entire paper by hand, or only the math dense portions?

Comment: I suspect that your question will be flagged as opinion based, anyway, there are two routes you can go: 1) Write by hand and use https://mathpix.com to produce the latex code and 2) set up your editor with snippets and shortcuts to make writing easier and faster, cf. https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/ (this is for vim, but other editors like emacs, vs code or sublime offer similar capabilities)

Comment: this can't really be answered, personally I have not drafted first with a pen for 30 years, but other people will differ. this question is likely to get closed for the site's standard "opinion based" reason. You may like mathpix which can make reasonable latex from scanned handwriting

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Rather than receive people's opinions, I'm looking for proven strategies that have been effective for people actually writing papers. Your response provides evidence from actual experience that typing directly in the drafting phase is effective for experienced LaTeX authors.

Comment: @DG. This is the best answer. I will try math pix and I will try your suggestions for speeding up my drafting. I think I just need more practice

Comment: I didn't vote, but calling people trolls doesn't encourage anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you ask for at least one effective workflow, which suits your needs. As I read it, you already described a mixed approach, accounting for the circumstances and conditions.

I suggest to:

- come up with a set of requirements, which can be evaluated or measured (small and complete, bijective enough so to say)
- develop a few more concepts (e.g. see some of the comments)
- try and evaluate them against said requirements with mathematical test texts
- learn from those trials and come up with a final approach
- keep the overall process in mind

Measurements might include:

- time needed (should be small)
- number of errors introduced (should be minimal)
- if in doubt favor good indication over exact measurement

**Example**

I like to get a taste of my final document quickly, which includes an effort estimation. For a small book project I needed many simple drawings. So I sketched them quickly on paper, scanned and included them in my Latex document.

That was fast, and the images roles and information were easy to literally see in the first draft.

Turning them into graphics via Tikz was feasible enough, at a later time, when my mind was free to do such routine tasks.

However, removing and harmonizing the last visual bumps and disharmonies were more time consuming than I expected.

Would I do it again this way? Yes, and I‘d have a checklist prepared meanwhile to:

- avoid known traps
- reuse insights and ways to do it
- speed things up,

which also makes it quite easy to account and adjust for new situations.

**Latex related …**

… is certainly the question, how to do such a checklist with Latex, which you can reuse and adjust quickly.

My favorite solution became using `hyperref`, which allows me to use checkboxes and text fields in a .pdf . See here on stackexchange for a [code example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/655011/245790).